# Is there a "furry" disadvantage for Kitsune/Kitsu?

Tags: l5r-4e

I was reading through the L5R 4th Ed books and stumbled across some bit of text that said something about certain characters having animalistic traits such as furry ears and slitted eyes as a result of a close bond to Chikushudo, and I believe it was related to the Unicorn or Fox clans but now I can't seem to find anything of the sort.

The closest things I've found are the Naga Ancestory and Child of Chikushudo Advantages (from Enemies of the Empire), neither of which really describes what I was thinking of. I could use the Disturbing Countenance Disadvantage to cover it, I'm sure, however it may not be a disadvantage after all since I can't seem to find it. Does anyone have any idea where I can find the passage in question?

Comment: Not certain, but I doubt there would be a disadvantage.
Many many notable rogukani heros have been kinda 'furry'.
There is a joke that one of the best ways to start a minor clan is to engage in bestiality (with a animal spirit). And starting a minor clan means that the Rokugani people (in particular the emperor), think you are pretty great.
Thus in L5R animal features are not hugely looks down on.
Not by people.

Comment: @Oxinabox Possibly, but I can't seem to find the passage in question. Any idea what page (or even book) I might have read that out of, based on the context?

Comment: It think it came up a game a ran.
I suspect Core or Emerald Empire since they are the books most player in my games have best access too.

Since last time I ran the only books out were Core, Emerald Empire, Great Clans and Enemies of the Empire,
It had to be one of those. Enemies is less likely as it is not got much PC stuff except for Ronin/Spider.
I don't have my L5R books with me (or I might attempt to answer the question.)

If you find it, do self answer.

Comment: Thanks, I'll focus on those if I don't get a response.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> At the end of the first century, the infant Fox Clan managed to survive in its strange new home by forming an alliance with the fox spirits of the Kitsune Mori - an arrangement that ultimately included intermarriage with the spirits in their human form. From time to time this spiritual heritage manifests itself in a young Kitsune who seems to communicate with animals instinctively who is more at home in the forest than in a house or temple, and who begins to show strange physical affinities to the fox spirits: green eyes, red or white hair, and even fur.
>
> In the early days of the clan, these strangely gifted individuals often lost their humanity to the allure of the fox spirits' wild and unfettered existence. Over the centuries, however, the Kitsune shugenja learned to recognize the symptoms of those whose connection to Chikushudo was dangerously strong. Eventually the family devised techniques of self-control and spiritual harmony that would let these individuals find a balance between their human and animal sides.
>
> -- "The Children of the Forest" Sidebar, page 65, **The Book of Earth**

So it seems the passage in question was not a Disadvantage in a mechanical sense but simply described what seems to be one. I am now reasonably convinced that the best ways to represent this are by reskinning certain other disadvantages (eg: **Disturbing Countenance**, **Lord Moon's Curse**) or better by using the **Child of Chikushudo** Advantage found on page 244 of **Enemies of the Empire**, which directly reflects a spiritual heritage.

Comment: Great answer. I'd add that if you meant to represent a case where one DID not undergo this special training by Kitsune shugenja (or did, but it failed) and thus retained his **dangerously** close connection to Animal Kingdom **without** control over it... then it's a disadvantage, equal in points to however strong you want it to be, but not stronger than the advantage Child of Chikushudo.

Comment: @LIttleAncientForestKami I was actually thinking to reskin "Lord Moon's Curse" for that.